# i am using VW and VH in website as unit but when i am opening my inspection tab my websites design shift upword,so how to solve the issue?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, viewport, viewport-units

I am new to web development.... please suggest me some solution for this issue I am using 'vw' for width and 'vh' for height but its not working well when i am opening my website in mobile and when i am opening website in laptop and opening tab of inspection my websites design goes up ,so i want so solution for solving this issue

I am trying this but its not working properly when i am open my inspection tab of browser ,Its change size according to view port size...please help me for solve this issue ...thank you....

below is HTML Code:-
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>
      iNotebook
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="Navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul type="none">
          <h1>iNotebook</h1>
          <a href="">Create Notes</a>
          <a href="">My Notes</a>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="CreatePageLogOut">
        <button class="Logout">Log Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainAddNotePage">
      <div class="secondAddNote">
        <h1>Create Notes</h1>
        <h5 style="font-size: large; margin-top: 1%;">Title</h5>
        <input type="text" id="AddNoteInpute" />
        <h5 style="font-size: large;margin-top: 1%;">Description</h5>
        <input type="text" id="AddNoteInpute" />
        <h5 style="font-size: large;margin-top: 1%;">Tag</h5>
        <input type="text" id="AddNoteInpute" />
        <div>
          <button class="AddNoteButton">Add Notes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

and below is css code:-
`

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


.Navbar{
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 172);
    height: 8vh;
    display: flex;
    
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 8vh;
    width: 25vw;
    color: white;
}

a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.CreatePageLogOut{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    width: 70vw;
}

.Logout{
    height: 5vh;
    width: 8vw;
    background-color: rgb(239, 56, 56);
    color: white;
    border: solid rgb(171, 163, 249);
    border-radius: 8%;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.mainAddNotePage{
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#AddNoteInpute{
    height: 8vh;
    width: 25vw;
}

.AddNoteButton{
    height: 8vh;
    width: 20vh;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(52, 52, 245);
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

`

When i am open my inspect then my view port height is changed and when i am open website in mobile and tap on input keyboard is come up and view port height of input element is changed...please help me to solve problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is because `vh` & `vw` are units relative to the viewport.

`vh` means `View-Port Height` when you say `10vh` it means **10% of Viewport Height**, the element will use the Size value equivalent to 8% of the Browser View-Port Height. Similarly, `vw` means `View-Port Width`. So, the results you are having are perfectly normal & not a problem.

I would recommend you to use `px` or `em` & `rem` for most of the sizing.

Like using `8vh` for `nav` is somewhat of a good choice because it will look good covering 8% of the View-Port, but having an `input` covering 8% of View-Port is not recommended. In smaller devices, it will always raise issues.

Please Take CSS Length Reference From [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)